# React App deployed checkout page looks different from localhost 3000

Tags: css, reactjs

Why The deployed looks different than the local host version. I want the subtotal block is on the right. it seems the local host version looks fine, but the deployed subtotal block moves to the bottom. In my code, I have left and right div, and flex div in css.

Checkout page in localhost 3000
[image]

Checkout page of deployed version
[image]

Comment: you are using the same browser for both ? are you sure it's the same version running on the 2 environments ?

Comment: Yes, I think i use the same version. I open the local host 3000 in the visual studio terminal using code "npm start" and open the deployed version using code: 1. npm run build, 2. firebase deploy --only hosting